# Find documents with overlapping array elements within same document

Tags: mongodb

Using MongoDB, I have documents with two flat arrays of strings. Like so:

```
[
  {
    "key": "find-me-1",
    "arrayA": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "arrayB": ["B", "D"]
  },
  {
    "key": "find-me-2",
    "arrayA": ["E", "F"]
    "arrayB": ["E"]    
  },
  {
    "key": "do-not-find-me",
    "arrayA": ["G","H"]
    "arrayB": ["X","Y","Z"]
  },  
]
```

Now I want to return all documents where `arrayA` and `arrayB` have at least one string in common. (I.e. `find-me-1` and `find-me-2` in the example above, but not `do-not-find-me`.)

It sounds simple and what I tried is:

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$in": [
      "$arrayA",
      "$arrayB"
    ]
  }
})
```

However, it doesn't work. I always get an empty result set.

What am I doing wrong? How to do this?

Playground link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/5mXBhtkSc9h

Comment: $setIntersection (with $size). [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CdN_QqRPmc2)